# unable to resolve unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, string, list, int, string-formatting

I have this call to this function pretest() from the function testcase() as:

```
def testcase():
    try:
        for i_num in range(1,3):
            calculated_val = PRE_SETS[i_num]
            pretest(control, i_phase, log, calculated_val[0])

def pretest(control, i_phase, log, calculated_val):
    details = hardwarecommand()
    monitor_vals += details[3+calculated_val]
    print(monitor_vals)

def hardwarecommand():
    response = self.sendrcv(defines.CMD_HW1])
    items = response.split(",")
    data = items[:defines.INDEX_TWENTY]
    return data
```

The defined variable values are:

```
PRE_SETS = [
    [defines.ID2],
    [defines.ID1],
    [defines.ID2, defines.ID2],
    [],
    [],
]
```

In the file Defines.py

```
ID1 = 0
ID2 = 1
ID3 = 2
CMD_HW1 = "@fetchshutter"
INDEX_TWENTY = 20
```

When I try to run the program, during the call for function pretest() inside def testcase, I get the following Exception:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Could someone let me know how to resolve this error? I think the way I decode calculated_val[0] is probably wrong?

Comment: It means you're adding an int to a list, ie my_list + my_int, can you share the `pretest`'s code?

Comment: @maor10 - Hi, updated the post with pretest's code. Am I missing some explicit casting or something which causes this error? Thanks!

Comment: What data type is `details`? Where does `monitor_vals` comes from?

Comment: @jfaccioni - Expanded hardwarecommands() function. monitor_vals is an int val which I am intending to calculate and print

Comment: According to you, the exception was triggered by a line in `pretest()`. Which line?

Comment: @jjramsey - the compiler shows the exception when the call to pretest is made from def testcase(). ie, the line - pretest(control, i_phase, log, calculated_val[0]). I am assuming I can't use calculated_val[0] as such?

Comment: @user5105767 you are right, I realised it as soon as I could try to reproduce it. I've deleted my answer. It is actually difficult trying to guess the root of the issue without a [Minimal Reproducible  Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's only one line with sums, and unfortunately a lot of info are missing:  `details` array, the `defines` object and the monitor_vals `variable` are all involved in that single line. Eliminating those variables and using those you provided I have no errors.